# How to do a AngularTS working search box?

Tags: html, angular

I need to make a working search box. This code doesn't work. Can you help me to fix it?

html:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #searchForm="ngForm">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

search-form Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-form',
  templateUrl: './search-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-form.component.css']
})
export class SearchFormComponent {

  users: User[];
  private s: String;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private router: Router, 
      private userService: UserService)  { }

      onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
      this.userService.findByFS(f.value).subscribe(data => {
              this.users = data;})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code. It should work like that. You can check usage at https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm.

Template:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
  <input name="search" type="search" ngModel placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-form',
  templateUrl: './search-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-form.component.css']
})
export class SearchFormComponent {
  users: User[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService)  {}

  onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    this.userService.findByFS(f.value.search).subscribe(data => this.users = data);
  }
}
```